# How To Convert all values of A Typescript Record into a single Array?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

Even if the question seems simple to me, I couldn't find an appropriate similar question on StackOverflow to mine.

I want to convert a Typescript `Record<string, number>` into a single `number[]` Array.

What is the easiest way possible to do that? I am searching for some kind of `flatMap` functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.values()` sounds like it would be what you're looking for. [Object.values() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgU1HAJgLhgJSSVAeaOASzAHMAaGMAVwFsAjBOAPhgF4YBvAWACgYYAQwwBGcnwH0MAJnH8YwDAGY5AXwDcfPqEiwAboIA21BBHYwA8vQBWSKADoDx0wApEyFAEp1QA)